# Billboard Scale

Tags: ppi

help! I need to design a billboard dimensions are 400h x 840w @ 72 ppi in RGB mode. the info I got says it's a 21:10 ratio. So what size should I make this in illustrator or photoshop? thanks!

Comment: Perhaphs... 840w x 400h? But I do not understand what units are you talking about. A billboard? are thoose inches? is it for a website? are thoose pixels?

Comment: I'm assuming those are cm which is about 13ft...though I find it odd that the dimensions would be in cm, but the resolution in inches. :)  Regardless, Rafael is correct...whatever units 400x840 is, that's how big you'd make your image file @ 72ppi. That's assuming you're using photoshop. If you're using illustrator, it doesn't matter, since there's no PPI to deal with with vector files.

Comment: @DA01 Nothing unusual about dimensions in cm and resolution in PPI/DPI—that’s the standard in most of the world. PPI and DPI are used even in fully metric countries, I’m guessing because they’re so abstract that they really don’t need to tell you anything much, other than 72 = screen, 300 = print, etc. I would personally not opt to make a 4,000 × 8,400 mm document (if we're guessing the unit of measurement right) in Photoshop and work in that. Way too big and unwieldy. I’d make a 500 × 1,050 mm document at 576 ppi and tell the printer to upscale when printing.

Comment: (And who requires 72 dpi for a billboard? That’s high! And why RGB if it’s for a billboard, i.e., for print? Something sounds quite fishy about this.)

Comment: RGB and 72ppi? Are you using Photoshop to create a "billboard" design? I doubt you would be using it for print cause for best quality you will need 300ppi.